# How to reduce the eggs from over burnt at the sides in a wok?

Tags: eggs

I usually throw 3 eggs in a bowl and stir (also known as scrambled eggs) until it become a mixture, then I throw into a wok and fry it. However, I always get the sides (the perimeter or the edges) burnt.

So, how do I prevent the sides from getting over cooked?

I want to cook like the picture below:

[image]

I don't want to over fried the edge (or the sides or the perimeter or the outer circle) as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: You might want to describe what kind of eggs you are making... is it scrambled eggs?  An egg "crepe" to roll up other foods in?  Also, diameter is the length of a line across a circle at the widest part, through the center; do you mean the perimeter, the edge?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I have added illustrations. Hope it helps.

Comment: My best guess from your pictures is: 1) Add a small amount of water, milk, or cream, perhaps 1 tsp per egg; 2) make sure to thoroughly beat the eggs, until they are fairly uniform in color--the white and yolk should be well mixed; 3) cook quite gently on a low flame.   This application might also work better in a flat-bottomed non-stick skillet, rather than a rounded wok--I cannot tell from the pictures due to the dark color what kind of pan you are using.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you feel you must use a wok for this? I've got a big carbon-steel wok proudly on display on my kitchen wall but I still reach into my cupboard for the tiny Teflon pan when I make scrambled eggs. Woks aren't meant for even or non-stick cooking.

Comment: @Aaronut, Oh I see - I never thought that Woks are not meant for even or non-stick cooking. Looks like I have to go shopping for a Teflon pan. By the way, can any flat pan perform the same task as Taflon. I got a silver flat pan which I use to use it.

Comment: Yes, any flat pan is fine. Teflon just makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fry an egg in a wok. Is it the easiest pan to use? Maybe not. But it is doable. I do it occasionally in mine. [Check out this video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgvYHPBGcNM)

A couple things.... play with your heat. It is possibly too high. You'll also want to make sure your Wok is well seasoned prior to using (I can't tell by your picture, but I'll assume it's carbon steel or cast iron). If it's well seasoned (as in the video)you simply have a round non-stick pan. If you set your heat right, you should be able to cook an egg like that in there. Also in your two pictures, the first egg looks scrambled quite a bit smoother before putting on the heat.

I would probably not pick anything like stainless steel though (most pans that are silver coloured), as they definitely won't be non-stick and will require a lot more oil to keep your egg from sticking.

Comment: Carbon steel doesn't really season the way cast iron does; seasoned cast iron works as well as a non-stick pan but a seasoned wok isn't that much better than lightly-greased stainless steel... it still sticks.

Comment: *shrug* I have a carbon steel wok and it seems to work a whole lot better than my stainless steel wok. Possibly not AS well, but still more than well enough to fry an egg.

Comment: That said, I have teflon pans too, and the large majority of the time I use them to fry eggs. I'm just saying it's entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

You didnt mention what temperature the flame is under your wok. Low, Medium or High. Also Powerburner on some cooktops. Maybe turn the flame down some.